# I have a user in SnowFlake which also uses PowerBI, INFORMATION_SCHEMA is missing in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the SnowFlake web interface, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is visible and accesible. When logging in to PowerBI, with exactly the same user, the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is not shown. The PowerBI report should contain data of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, how can I get this to be visible in PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PowerBI's native connector to Snowflake?  Have you tried with the ODBC connector option instead?  I ask because I've seen differences in native connectors versus the ODBC option and it's possible the native connector has some limitations that PowerBI can help work out with their native Snowflake connector. Note that the PowerBI team maintains/owns the native connector to Snowflake so you can follow-up with them.

There's also the potential option of using ACCOUNT_USAGE views instead of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA depending on what the user is looking for.